# How to check if class was added with javascript?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I add a class to an input field when the text changes using jquery in the document.onready function.

`$('#formid2 input').on('change', function (e) {
               $(this).addClass('changed');

            });`

Is there a way to verify using chrome dev tools whether the class was really added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the input field, click on `inspect element`, and then look at the html to see if it is there. Inside the `<input>` tag you should see `class="changed"` or whatever the name of the class is that you added.

Comment: you're right. the actual error in my code ended up being something else. feeling pretty stupid now.